# Twitter - How to fetch user background image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm using Twitter in my iPhone app (ios 4 so not the built in framework..)

I searched the Twitter API docs, but I can't find, how do I get the user's background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a GET request to the following url and parse the JSON. You are looking for the `profile_background_image_url` entity.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=__some_username__&include_entities=true
```

More info here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

Comment: I don't think that's possible.